# Method is undefined minecraft

Tags: java

Working on a Minecraft mod and the title comes up for the following bit of code

```
this.getNavigator().setAvoidsWater(true);
this.getNavigator().setCanSwim(false);
this.getNavigator().setEnterDoors(true);
this.getNavigator().setAvoidSun(false);
this.getNavigator().setBreakDoors(false);
```

like for the first line all I get is

The method setAvoidsWater(boolean) is undefined for the type PathNavigate

Looked all over but others weren't having anything like this unless I over looked something.

Comment: these are custom methods, may be from interface which you need to implement

Comment: blah...why didn't I realize that in the first place.